# Rails 7/Production - Are you trying to open an SSL connection to a non-SSL Puma?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, ssl, ruby-on-rails-7

I keep getting this error in production mode `HTTP parse error, malformed request: #<Puma::HttpParserError: Invalid HTTP format, parsing fails. Are you trying to open an SSL connection to a non-SSL Puma?` in Rails v7.0.1 and i have no idea why. I tried everything from other solutions, which are mostly related to local environment, but I keep getting this in production.

I already set `config.force_ssl` to `true`.

**Nginx Conf**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name api.example.com;
    return 308 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name api.example.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.exaple.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

    location / {
    proxy_pass http://1.1.1.1:3000;
    proxy_redirect http://1.1.1.1:3000 https://api.example.com;
    }
}
```

Previously this setup has worked for me. Please help, I'm going insane right now.

**Gemfile**

```rb
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '3.0.0'

gem 'pg', '>= 1.1'
gem 'puma', '~> 5.5'
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails', branch: 'main'
gem 'rails', '~> 7.0.0'
gem 'bootsnap', require: false
gem 'jwt'
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: %i[mingw mswin x64_mingw jruby]
# Use Rack CORS for handling Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS), making cross-origin AJAX possible
gem 'rack-cors'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'debug', platforms: %i[mri mingw x64_mingw]
  gem 'spring'
end

group :development do
  gem 'solargraph'
end
```

Comment: You should use nginx for SSL termination and not trying to send HTTPS to your backend, replace `proxy_pass https://1.1.1.1:3000;` with `proxy_pass http://1.1.1.1:3000;`.

Comment: @IvanShatsky oops, mistake on my part. That didn't fix my issue though.

Comment: I don't know what `config.force_ssl` is, but once more, all the SSL termination should be done and ended up with nginx, nginx to ruby communications should go unencrypted (unless they are taking place over some external connections),  maybe you don't need that `config.force_ssl` to be set to `true`?

Comment: @IvanShatsky setting `config.force_ssl` to `true` was one of the solutions I found that worked for some people, but in my situation it being true or false didn't change anything.

Comment: `Previously this setup has worked for me. Please help, I'm going insane right now.` Could you add when it started throwing this error?

Comment: @Moussa I'm deploying a different app, I should've clarified that. I basically used the same nginx config for a previous project and it works perfectly. Now I'm trying to do the same for a new project and it's not working.

Comment: Did the previous project use Rails 7 too?

Comment: @Moussa it did not, it used Rails 6. I've been trying to find if there issues related to this in Rails 7 but haven't been able to find anything